# How to delete file from SVN remote repository using python svn module

Tags: python, svn

Is there any way to delete a file from SVN remote repository in python script using [svn 0.3.45](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svn)?

I am able to add and commit new files, however I cannot figure out how to delete file in local repo, and commit this 'information' to remote repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find a solution using svn module. What I did I simply used `subprocess` module:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call('svn delete {}'.format(file))
```